# Bulk patenting discounts?

Tags: fees, payment

I have many different inventions to patent - not just multiple independent claims, but several completely different and entirely unrelated inventions (for example, one is an automotive technology and another is a medical device; completely unrelated).

Will I save on fees by patenting them at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

There are no bulk filing fees at the U.S. Patent Office.  http://www.uspto.gov/learning-and-resources/fees-and-payment/uspto-fee-schedule

There are discounts such as the micro entity and small entity fee schedules if you qualify.   However, the micro-entity works against bulk filing.

If you are planning on using a patent attorney or patent agent to prepare and file your patent applications, you may certainly be able to negotiate a bulk discount on the fees for their services.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  What do you mean by "micro-entity works against bulk filing?"  I know that a requirement for micro-entity is that I am not named on more than four previous applications, but it says nothing about filing more than four patents at once.  Thanks again.